# An integral where nothing is working

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{\sqrt{x^4-1}}$$ I tried using some substitution but after each root the expression is changing so it is not of any help. Also integration by parts also not work here because there is no opening.

Comment: it is $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$\ln|x+{\sqrt{x^2+1}}|-\ln|x+{\sqrt{x^2-1}}|+C$$ $|x|$>$1$